# Wie kann ich das "h" in Themperatur etablieren?

Tags: spelling, reformed-orthography

Thermometer, Thermostat, thermische Energie... schreibt man alles mit "h".
Nur bei der Themperatur fehlt das h normalerweise. Ich selbst schreibe absichtlich das "h" mit rein, in der Hoffnung, dass sich diese meiner Meinung nach korrektere, weil konsistentere, Schreibweise durchsetzt.

Allerdings habe ich wenig Hoffnung, dass das alleine ausreicht, um dem Diktat der deutschen Rechtschreibung zu trotzen.
Welche Schritte muss ich gehen, um die Wahrscheinlichkeit zu erhöhen, dass diese Schreibweise sich offiziell durchsetzt? An welche offizielle Stelle kann ich mich wenden?

Comment: Warum sollte etwas etabliert werden, was weder nötig noch sinnvoll ist? Setzen Sie Ihre Kräfte lieber für die Abschaffung von "h" in den anderen "termo"-Wörtern ein!

Comment: @Eller Auch die Abschaffung wäre weder nötig noch sinnvoll.

Comment: @Uwe natürlich wäre die Abschaffung sinnvoll. Wer braucht denn einen Buchstaben, der außer Platz nehmen keine andere Funktion hat?! Deutsch ist nicht Griechisch und "h" hat nun keine Berechtuigung für Dasein.

Comment: @Eller If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: Das Anliegen, eine Schreibweise mit Hilfe einer offiziellen Stelle durchzusetzen, um *dem Diktat der deutschen Rechtschreibung zu trotzen* entbehrt m.E. irgendwie einer gewissen Konsistenz der logischen Argumentation.

Comment: @Uwe Ein konsequenter Mann würde dann auch heute noch "Thräne" und "Threue" schreiben (war ja auch nichts "broke" daran), was Sie aber bestimmt nicht thun.

Comment: Temperament, Tempo, Tempel... versus Thermalbad, Themenwechsel... Die Wortherkunft trägt mit zur Eindeutigkeit bei, sonst wären wir längst auch bei "Warheit" und "Dicktat" angelangt, die dann nicht mehr von Komposita zu unterscheiden wären.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Deine Meinung ist einfach falsch:

"Thermo-" ist zurückzuführen [auf das griechische "thermós (θερμός)"](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Thermometer), "Temperatur" dagegen [auf das lateinische "temperātūra"](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Temperatur).

Da die Entwicklung der deutschen Rechtschreibung eher in Richtung Vereinfachung geht, ist es wahrscheinlicher, dass das stumme h in aus dem Griechischen stammenden Fremdwörtern verschwindet, als dass ein zusätzliches stummes h in Wörter eingefügt wird.

Du kannst versuchen, Dein Ansinnen beim [Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/) anzubringen, wirst aber aufgrund mangelnder logischer Argumente keinen Erfolg haben.

Answer (score 1):

Mal abgesehen von der Konsistenz mit der griechischen Etymologie, gibt es auch ein orthographisches Argument gegen **Themperatur*: Das *h* ist ein Dehnungszeichen, das normalerweise hinter dem Vokal steht, nur das *t* zieht es zu sich – das gilt in der griechischen Transkription von Theta vs. Tau genauso wie in der deutschen (Fraktur-) Orthographie des späten 19. Jahrhunderts, die sich bis vor kurzem bspw. in *Thunfisch* erhalten hatte. Beide *e* in *Temperatur* werden aber kurz gesprochen.